# DB2 Sequence value using Java

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I need to get the next value from a DB2 sequence. This is one approach I've tried

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("db2 VALUES NEXTVAL FOR <sequence_name>"); 

rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: [ibm][db2][jcc][10103][10941] Method executeQuery cannot be used for updates.
           at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.qh.a(qh.java:2390)
           at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.qh.a(qh.java:1751)
           at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.qh.a(qh.java:478)
           at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.qh.executeQuery(qh.java:462)
           at test.pack.SequenceConn.getNextSequenceValue(SequenceConn.java:59)
           at test.pack.SequenceConn.main(SequenceConn.java:22)
```

How can I retrieve the next value from the sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to solve this by myself.

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("VALUES NEXTVAL FOR <sequence_name>"); 

rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

Basically the preceding `db2` in the query string was causing the issue. Removed it and was able to get the sequence value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following sentence to retrieve the next value for a sequence in DB2:

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence_name>"); 
if(rs.next()) {
    Long sequenceValue = rs.getLong(1);
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

As specified in the [DB2 Reference chapter on Sequences](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0023464.htm).

> **NEXT VALUE FOR sequence-name**
>           A NEXT VALUE expression generates and returns the next value for the sequence specified by sequence-name.
>   ...
>   
>     - NEXT VALUE and PREVIOUS VALUE expressions can be specified in the following places:
>              · select-statement or SELECT INTO statement (within the select-clause, provided that the statement does not contain a DISTINCT keyword, a GROUP BY clause, an ORDER BY clause, a UNION keyword, an INTERSECT keyword, or EXCEPT keyword)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Tried it out and stumbled onto the next error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: END-OF-STATEMENT;READ FOR <sequence_name>;<table_expr> . Tried quickly google for solution but haven't found one so far.

Comment: @Jayp: Do not include the `;` in your SQL string from Java. And only execute a single SQL statement per call to `executeQuery()`

Comment: The string is exactly like Xavi's above.